# What is the variable(s) or such written before the integration symbol?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, applications, mathematical-astronomy

From 'Distance measures (cosmology)' on Wikipedia:

> Cosmologists commonly use the following measures for distances from the observer to an object at redshift $z$ along the line of sight:
>
> - **Comoving distance:**
>   $$d_C(z)=d_H\int_0^z\frac{dz'}{E(z')}.$$
> - **Transverse comoving distance:**
>   $$d_M(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
>   \frac{d_H}{\sqrt{\Omega_k}}\sinh\left(\frac{\sqrt{\Omega_k}d_C(z)}{d_H}\right) & \Omega_k>0,\\
>   d_C(z) & \Omega_k=0,\\
>   \frac{d_H}{\sqrt{|\Omega_k|}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{|\Omega_k|}d_C(z)}{d_H}\right) & \Omega_k<0.
>   \end{array}\right.$$
> - **Angular diameter distance:**
>   $$d_A(z)=\frac{d_M(z)}{1+z}.$$
> - **Luminosity distance:**
>   $$d_L(z)=(1+z)d_M(z).$$
> - **Light-travel distance:**
>   $$d_T(z)=d_H\int_0^z\frac{dz'}{(1+z')E(z')}.$$
>
> Note that the comoving distance is recovered from the transverse comoving distance by taking the limit $\Omega\to0$, such that the two distance measures are equivalent in a flat universe.

What do you do with the dH that comes up before the integration symbol under 'comoving distance' and 'light-travel distance'?

Not just here, but in general...

Also, the z is a constant in astronomy, so how do you take the derivatives of z in those same two equations?  If the derivative of a constant is always 0?  It doesn't make sense to me....

P.S.  I posted something similar in Astronomy S.E., I hope that is okay... Here, I wanted to understand the general math aspect...

Comment: What do you mean by your question *what do you do* with $d_H$?

Comment: Since $z$ is a constant, the article seems to use $z'$ to indicate a variable

Comment: This is not a math question but a cosmology one. $d_H\neq dH$. It's a constant known as the Hubble distance, not an integration differential. Also $z$ is not a constant, it's a redshift. You can think of it as a backwards looking time parameter. Does it make sense that it is not a constant because different objects would have been emitting light to us at different times?

Comment: But, still, Ninad and gt6989b, how do you take the differential of a variable without an exponent?  Isn't it always going to be 1?  And the value of z at any particular time is going to be a constant, a number, whose differential is always 0....

Comment: That's not what they're doing, so this Wikipedia article is irrelevant. Indeed, at the start of the Wikipedia section being quoted, they state that the Hubble distance is 
$$d_{H}={\frac {c}{H_{0}}}\approx 3000h^{-1}{\text{Mpc}}\approx 9.26\cdot 10^{25}h^{-1}{\text{m}}$$ where $h$ is the (not precisely known) dimensionless Hubble constant. It's like saying distance equals speed times time, so $v=d/t$. $d$ is just a length.

Comment: That's like saying because an event happens at some timestamp $t=t_0$ then time is a constant. That makes no sense. The interpretation is always differentiate first, plug in second, when a value for a variable is known, just like how $$f'(0) \neq (f(0))'$$

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite the equations with every "calculus $\mathrm d$" deitalicised, so$$d_C(z)=d_H\int_0^z\tfrac{\mathrm dz^\prime}{E(z^\prime)},\,d_T(z)=d_H\int_0^z\tfrac{\mathrm dz^\prime}{(1+z^\prime)E(z^\prime)}.$$The other equations don't contain any such $\mathrm d$, so I won't reproduce those. For all the difference it makes, $d_A,\,d_C,\,d_H,\,d_L,\,d_M,\,d_T$ might as well have been called $r_A,\,r_C,\,r_H,\,r_L,\,r_M,\,r_T$.

It helps to understand why these definite integrals start at $0$. The value of $a:=1+z$ is proportional to the width of the universe, so is a function of time. The usual convention is to take $a=1$, or equivalently $z=0$, in the present day. Then $d_C,\,d_T$ are distances from our present-day location to something observed by dint of light it emitted in the past: in particular, these distances are $0$ if $z=0$.

Of course, $z=0\implies d_C=d_T=0\implies d_A=d_L=d_M=0$. But $d_H$ is approximately proportional to $a$.

Comment: So, just to be sure (I can be very slow), $d_H$ is a coefficient or constant to be multiplied by the result of the following integration?